# `sbt package` results in huge war file - how to make it smaller?

Tags: scala, war, lift, sbt

I'm currently using SBT to manage my Lift project. I'd like to deploy it, but when I run 'sbt package' it produces a 60MB war file. This seems pretty large - are there ways I could cut down the size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was because 'sbt package' was following symlinks and packed all my images into the warfile. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: You should post this as a comment to Don's answer and delete this post.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) could help.

Comment: Turns out it was because 'sbt package' was following symlinks and packed all my images into the warfile. Thanks for the tip anyway!